# unable to create a database connection using Aqua Data Studio ETL tool

Tags: db2, zos, ibm-data-studio

When try to connect to DB2 Z/OS, the following error message is displayed,

> [jcc][t4][10509][13454][3.67.28] Connection to the data server failed. The IBM Data Server for JDBC and SQLJ license was invalid or was not activated for the DB2 for z/OS subsystem. If you are connecting directly to the data server and using DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System z, perform the activation step by running the activation program in the license activation kit. If you are using any other edition of DB2 Connect, obtain the license file, db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar, from the license activation kit, and follow the installation directions to include the license file in the class path. ERRORCODE=-4230, SQLSTATE=42968"

Comment: So, what part of the error message seems unclear?

Answer (score 0):

For a ADS DB2 Z/OS connection,you do need the DB2 z/OS JDBC driver license file.  You can fix the problem below with these steps ...

1. Close ADStudio
2. Download this driver file
3. Unzip the contents into the /lib/drivers> folder
4. Start ADStudio and then connect to DB2 z/OS.